# Parse Push notification installation data broswer does not equal with users download and updated - IOS

Tags: ios, notifications, parse-platform

I met a problem when I submit my app to app store and have users updated and downloaded around 1000+(Google analytic) but in data browser of parse notification I saw only 553 users register notification. Any body knew which point went wrong, because I don't know why.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe parse just count them if they accept the push notification permissions

Comment: Yes, I think so, but the number of installation(updated, install app for appstore) 1000+ and in data browser store only 553 users. I think it might be has problems. And thank you @jcesarmobile for your replying.